# Using regex, how would I match strings between pipe characters (|) but allow escaping of the pipe character?

Tags: regex

If I want to match strings (without newlines) in between pipe | characters, BUT allow escaping of pipes (|) to prevent ending the match, how would I write that? e.g.:

```
|one|two| // two matches ('one', 'two')

|o\|ne|two| // should also match twice ('o\|ne', 'two')
```

The matches should be the strings in between the pipes, not the pipes themselves. In other words, in the first line the match should be "one", and "two", and in the second line it should be "o|ne" and "two".

I'm imagining it's something to do with a negative lookbehind perhaps, and I can get that to work to match just the pipes themselves, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the contents themselves.

Here is my poor attempt that fails for the escaped characters: `[^\|\s]+`

(https://regex101.com/r/lUUTK4/1)

Comment: Do you mean `"|o\\|ne|two|"`? Most languages convert `"|o\|ne|two|"` to `"|o|ne|two|"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(?:\\.|[^|\s])+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BJ3kvs/1). *Details*:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `\\.` - a `\` char and then any single char other than line break chars
- `|` - or

  - `[^|\s]` - any char other than `|` and whitespace
- `)+` - end of the group, repeat one or more times.

To also support escaped line break chars, use one of the supported variants:

```
(?s)(?:\\.|[^|\s])+
(?:\\[\w\W]|[^|\s])+
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you wish to match strings that contain pipes preceded by a backslash and characters other than pipes. We can translate that statement directly to a regular expression:

```
(?:(?<=\\)\||[^|])+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/62MvBZ/1)

This expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?:       # begin non-capture group
  (?<=\\) # positive lookbehind asserts that current string location
          # is preceded by a backslash
  \|      # match a pipe
  |       # or
  [^|]    # match a character other than a pipe
)+        # end non-capture group and execute one or more times
```

You may also wish to hover the cursor over each part of the expression at the link to obtain an explanation of its function.